# ¿Obtener registro dentro de un array con valor mas grande y usarlo como condición en $match?

Tags: mongodb

estoy tratando de resolver una consulta sobre una colección con una estructura similar a esta:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5fa5505623bd7e1c07e1ce68"),
"fechaApertura" : [ 
    {
        "_id_batch" : "3f0e31aa-5065-4c74-b788-b3bf6e63f248",
        "_value" : ISODate("2020-07-04T21:45:00.123Z"),
        "_created_at" : ISODate("2020-11-06T13:32:06.013Z"),
        "_origin" : "ingesta"
    }, 
    {
        "_id_batch" : "3f0e31aa-5065-4c74-b788-b3bf6e63f249",
        "_value" : ISODate("2020-07-04T20:00:00.123Z"),
        "_created_at" : ISODate("2020-11-06T21:19:25.376Z"),
        "_origin" : "ingesta"
    }
] }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener todos los registros cuyo _value este dentro de un rango pero el _value con el que voy a hacer la comparación tiene que ser de aquel registro cuyo _created_at sea el mas actualizado, en el ejemplo anterior espero obtener el registro si  esta dentro del rango ISODate("2020-07-04T19:00:00.123Z") y ISODate("2020-07-04T20:30:00.123Z")

Comment: No se comprende totalmente lo que deseas, ¿puedes mostrar un ejemplo de salida esperada y lo que has intentado para lograrlo? Saludos

Comment: Lo que deseo  hacer es es obtener el registro con la fecha _created_at mas actualizada, el el ejemplo anterior  es el ultimo registro (con "_id_batch" = "3f0e31aa-5065-4c74-b788-b3bf6e63f249") , debo obtener el ultimo registro porque este registro lo voy a utilizar para realizar sobre el campo _value  unas serie de consultas. Lo que busco es poder trabajar con el valor mas reciente.